# How to install cm-super fonts on Windows?

Tags: fonts, installing-fonts

I'd like to intsall cm-super fonts (Type 1) on Windows 7 without installing any other package, so that I can use them in Adobe Illustrator. Now, the problem is that [the package](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ps-type1/cm-super) doesn't include PFM files. I've [read](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/872a2438-481d-4fb4-bdc5-95797fc307aa/type-1-fonts-and-windows-7?forum=w7itproui) that the PFM files are needed in order to install Type 1 fonts on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It includes the `.afm` files and you have the free converter tool `afmtopfm`, available [here](https://www.proximasoftware.com/afmtopfm/).